# Information Governance Retention Policy Orphan Lock

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing, retention, compliance-center

We setup a Retention Policy on all sites under the Information Governance section of the M365 Compliance center. It locked all sites from deletion and won't let users delete folders with files in them.

We turned this off last week and it still won't let us delete anything. How long does it take to get rid of the retention policy and unlock site deletion?

[image]

[image]

EDIT
Do NOT Enable Retention in Compliance center. It is a can of worms that will cost you time and money. MS has a huge bug they are failing to address right now that is costing our organization tens of thousands of dollars and they will not escalate the ticket beyond simple support tier.

Comment: Have you taken a look here? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/remove-a-sharepoint-site-on-preservation-hold/m-p/21196

Comment: cmdlets don't work from 5 years ago

Comment: We are running into the same issue. Created a retention policy and then later deleted it. I now can't delete any SharePoint sites (Document Center). We get the "This site has a compliance policy set to block deletion." error. I have a ticket open with MSFT. Have you gotten anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Solved the Issue after finally Escalating. Not much details were given on the fix, only that there was a tenant wide lock or "Hold" on every site collection. We can now delete sites again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a major bug in retention policy.
My organization has a retention policy applied on O365 groups, so the sharepoint sites associated with the O365 group also fall under the retention policy.
Strangely we can still delete any O365 group but the SharePoint Site associated with it is not getting deleted automatically and gives warning/error "This site has a compliance policy set to block deletion". This has become a major concern for as the no of SharePoint sites created due to O365 groups are getting increased, though we are able to delete the O365 group but cannot delete the SharePoint Site.

I have opened a ticket with Microsoft and escalated it to the Product team, but they are also struggling to find out why this is happening.  Moreover they themself are not aware of how exactly retention policy is working for O365 groups.

Comment: Huge bug they need to address. Our org has declined to use this going forward. We had to purchase a third party tool. Some are even migrating to Content Server

Answer (score -1):

Does the issue occur to one site or all sites? One item or all items? Switch to admin account and check if he can delete the site.

1.Check the retention policy status. Off(Success)?

[image]

[image]

2.To check the hold settings, make sure you go to Office 365 admin center -> Security -> eDiscovery, check if there is any case, open the case ->choose the “Hold” tab to see if there’s any hold settings.

Comment: I set it to "OFF" for 5 days, then deleted the Policy completely 3 days ago.. Still, every single site is locked.

Comment: I suggest you open a service request to check backend retention policy.

Comment: I did. That was 2 days ago and MS said it would take 11 minutes to call